# Replacing a calculated field column with a Blank when a NULL is returned?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, converters, varchar

I'm doing a simple query that uses the DateDiff function to find the number of days between the dates. However, with regards to certain instances, I'd like to populate a blank field (not a null).

Something like this is what I currently have, and it seems to work fine (but it populates a null).

```
 [Test (Years)] = CASE WHEN TYPE IN ('A','B') 
 THEN NULL ELSE IsNull(CONVERT(decimal(28,12),
 (DATEDIFF(d,@StartDate,ExpirationDate)))/365,0) END
```

Now if I try something like this... which tries to convert all TYPE A and B to populate a blank, I'll get the following error message: `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

```
 [Test (Years)] = CASE WHEN TYPE IN ('A','B') 
 THEN '' ELSE IsNull(CONVERT(decimal(28,12),
 (DATEDIFF(d,@StartDate,ExpirationDate)))/365,0) END
```

Is there a simple thing I'm missing? I've tried doing the calcualtions without converting to a decimal, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Well how do you expect to store a blank string in a numeric?

Comment: I don't, that's why I'm not sure if I can use another sort of CONVERT or CAST to do so, or if there is some sort of workaround for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` is an expression that returns exactly one value and all of the branches must yield compatible types. A string (even a blank string) is not compatible with a decimal, so you need to do something like:

```
CASE WHEN ... THEN '' ELSE 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), COALESCE(CONVERT(DECIMAL(23,12), ... ,0)) END
```

Note that this hack will only work if you are presenting the data to an end user. If you are trying to store this data in a column or use it in other calculations, it too will be tripped up by the blank string. A number can't be a blank string:

```
DECLARE @i INT = '';
SELECT @i;
```

Result:

```
0
```

So, if you don't want "empty" numerics to be interpreted as 0, stop being afraid of `NULL` and if you are dealing with this at presentation time, have the presentation layer present a blank string instead of `NULL`.